# bindAsContract equivalent in Google/Guice

Tags: java, guice, hk2

Can someone point me to the equivalent of HK2's bindAsContract in Google Guice?

Example in HK2:

```
public static class Binder extends AbstractBinder {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bindAsContract(MyClass.Factory.class).in(Singleton.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: I haven't used guice in while, but AFAICR, can't you just use `bind` by itself with guice? `bindAsContact` is just short hand for `bind(Some.class).to(Some.class)`. Maybe I'm wrong but I think that's what `bind` by itself does in guice, if you are using the `AbstractModule`

Comment: have you tried `bind(MyClass.Factory.class).in(Singleton.class)`?

Comment: Yeah I guess I should have closed this. I did end up using `bind(MyClass.Factory.class).in(Singleton.class)`. Feel free to put your response in an answer and i'll accept it. Thanks